# How do I update column with NULL values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables

Tb1

```
ID  Name  Birthdate
--------------------
1   Ball  NULL
2   Tire  2022-01-01
3   Ball  1900-01-01
```

Tb2

```
ID     Name  Birthdate
------------------------
NULL   Ball  NULL
NULL   Tire  2022-01-01
NULL   Ball  1900-01-01
```

I want to update `Tb2.ID` to follow `Tb1.ID`, so here is my script

```
UPDATE Tb2.ID = Tb1.ID
FROM Tb2
LEFT JOIN Tb1 ON Tb2.Name = Tb1.Name
              AND ISNULL (Tb2.Birthdate, '') = ISNULL (Tb1.Birthdate, '')
WHERE Tb2.ID IS NULL
```

And the result is ID 1 has 2 rows in Tb2 as seen like this table

| ID | Name | Birthdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ball | NULL |
| 2 | Tire | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | Ball | 1900-01-01 |

My expectation is ID 3 is updated to Tb2 for this record

```
ID   Name   Birthdate
----------------------
3    Ball   1900-01-01
```

Can you guys help?

I suspect in the script goes wrong in join condition for `Birthdate`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
UPDATE Tb2
SET Tb2.ID = Tb1.ID
FROM Tb2
LEFT JOIN Tb1
ON Tb2.Name = Tb1.Name
AND ISNULL(Tb2.Birthdate,'9999-12-31') = ISNULL(Tb1.Birthdate,'9999-12-31')
WHERE Tb2.ID IS NULL
```

I think the empty strings convert to 1900-01-01 in your ISNULLs, using an invalid (but not 1900-01-01) date for NULL birth dates would address that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2022 (or later), you can also use the new [`IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) syntax. This allows for comparing both null and non-null values.

```
UPDATE Tb2
SET ID = Tb1.ID
FROM Tb2
JOIN Tb1
    ON Tb2.Name = Tb1.Name
    AND Tb2.Birthdate IS NOT DISTINCT FROM Tb1.Birthdate
WHERE Tb2.ID IS NULL
```

Note that there is no need for a left join, since you really only want to update when you have a match. Use an inner join instead.

See also [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/56k7_IrY) for a quick `DISTINCT FROM` demo.